# replace matches with values from other file

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

I have a file that consists of many tables that contain data about certain coordinates. Each table is separated by a line with the word "Coords".

```
Coords
Table 1
Coords 
Table 2
Coords
Table 3
...
```

In a separate file, I have a list of all of the coordinates that match the tables.

```
Coordinate 1
Coordinate 2
Coordinate 3
...
```

What I am trying to do is replace the first instance of "Coords" with the first line of the coordinates file, the second instance with the second line, etc.

```
Coordinate 1
Table 1
Coordinate 2
Table 2
Coordinate 3
Table 3
...
```

I've tried this:

```
while read coord
do
    perl -pln -e 's/Coords/$coord/' Tables >> Output
done <Coordinates
```

But it didn't work. (Because perl cannot use bash variables?) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using double quotes instead? Also, `-p` and `-n` are mutually exclusive (as they do the same thing, except for a print).

Comment: Yes, but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a trivial one-liner with `awk`:

```
awk '/Coords/{getline<"coords.txt"}1' template.txt
```

A slightly less fun one that reads the coordinates file into memory:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{repl[NR]=$0;next}/Coords/{$0=repl[++n]}1' coords.txt template.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/Coords/{Rcoord.txt' -e 'd}' template.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily, you just need to break it down into manageable steps.

> What I am trying to do is replace the first instance of "Coords" with
>   the first line of the coordinates file, the second instance with the
>   second line, etc.

Lets see if we can break this up:

1. Read data from the coordinates file (possibly into a List)
2. Loop through your placeholder file line by line searching for `Coords`
3. If you find a match, overwrite that line with the next line from the coordinates file (using `shift` will extract the first value from the coordinates list)

Here is what that *might* look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

# open the coordinates file for reading
open(my $coord_fh, '<', 'coordinates.txt');

# read the file (line by line) into a List
my @coordinates = <$coord_fh>;

# close coordinate filehandle
close($coord_fh);

# open the other file for reading
open(my $other_fh, '<', 'otherfile.txt');

# save the lines you process
my @lines;

# first coordinate
my $coord = shift @coordinates;

# read line by line seraching for Coord
# replace with shift @coordinates if found
while ( my $line = <$other_fh> ) {
    if( $line =~ s/Coords/$coord/ ) {
        # get next coordinate
        $coord = shift @coordinates;
    }

    # save line
    push @lines, $line;
}

# close file for reading
close($other_fh);


# write all of the lines back to your file
open(my $out_fh, '>', 'otherfile.txt');

print {$out_fh} "$_" foreach(@lines);
```

Comment: I received the following error "Use of uninitialized value $coord in substitution (s///) at PerlCoorder line 26, <$other_fh> line 364525." But I commented out use strict and use warnings and it seemed to work perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: Removing strict and warnings to get rid of a warning is like putting a sticker over the oil warning lamp in your car. In other words, not a good idea.

Comment: @JT It executed without error or warnings on my machine. Did you make any changes ?

Comment: @JT, you probably have fewer lines in coordinates.txt than you have occurrences of "Coords" in otherfile.txt.  When `@coordinates` is empty, you start trying to substitute in `undef`, which generates that warning.

Comment: @cjm That is, in fact, the case. Thanks for helping